# insert template in cs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-4.0, devexpress

Im using aspxGridView control. It has templates inside. In aspx file I can write like:
So aspxGridView control has got templates and one of them is StatusBar. Now I would like to set that status bar template which as You can see contains html and so on in my cs file so that I can modify it from cs file for each aspxGridView.

```
<aspxgridView>
...
 <Templates>
            <StatusBar>
                <div id="StatusBarDiv" runat="server" align="right">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <dxe:ASPxLabel ID="Title" runat="server" Text="records per page:">
                                </dxe:ASPxLabel>
                            </td>                    
                            <td>
...
```

Because its kind of gridView and I have a lot of them in my project I wanted to add this template to each one in default.master.cs file.

I iterate through each control, check if its aspxGridView control and if yes I would like to add that template but I dont know how to add it from cs file :/

thanks for any help on doing that

Comment: I think more information is required in order to obtain an answer coherent and succinct enough for your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement a template in runtime, you should create a special class which will support the [ITemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.aspx) interface and set the ASPxGridView.Templates.StatusBar property to an instance of this class.  For more details, please refer to the following [examples](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=ITemplate&p=T4|P5|57).